# Limit Character Input in 2D Array

Tags: c++, arrays, user-input

I am trying to create a mini-database for phones. It utilizes a 2D array so I can have a list of 1000 phones. However, its product ID must only have 4 characters. I wanted it to be a 4 character C-string.

Here is the initialized productID variable:`char productID[1000][5]`. After doing it, I tried to make sure the user entered how many phones they wanted and enter the ID. However, everytime I try to input an ID regardless of character length. It keeps looping, "It has to be four characters." Is there a way to only implement this when anything but four characters are sent from the keyboard?

```
 for (int c= 0; c<n; c++)
{
    cout<<"Enter the product ID."<<endl;
    for(int b=0; b<5; b++)
    {
    cin>>productID[b];

    while (productID[c][b]>5)
    {
        cout<<"It has to be four characters."<<endl;
        cin>>productID[b];
    }
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why do you have an array length of 5, if you want only 4 characters?
Ah, I just thought you needed only letters... Well like that, it is more complicated condition. Both variants posted:

```
#include <string.h>

char productID[1000][4];
for (int c= 0; c<4; c++)
{
    std::cout<<"Enter the product ID."<<std::endl;

    std::cin>>productID[c];

    for(int b=0; b<4; b++)
    {
        while (strlen(productID[c])>4 || !((productID[c][b]>='A' && productID[c][b]<='Z')||(productID[c][b]>='a' && productID[c][b]<='z')) )
        {
            std::cout<<"It has to be four letters."<<std::endl;
            std::cin>>productID[c];
        }
    }
}


for (int c= 0; c<4; c++)
{
    std::cout<<"Enter the product ID."<<std::endl;

    std::cin>>productID[c];
    int length = strlen(productID[c]);
    while (length != 4) //replace with "> 4" if it can be less than 4 char. 
    {
        std::cout<<"It has to be four characters."<<std::endl;
        std::cin>>productID[c];
    }
}

        #include <cctype>
        while (strlen(productID[c])>4 
               || !isalpha(productID[c][0])
               || !isalpha(productID[c][1])
               || !isdigit(productID[c][2])
               || !isdigit(productID[c][3])
              )
        {
            std::cout<<"It has to be ..."<<std::endl;
            std::cin>>productID[c];
        }
```

Comment: I was including NULL \0 as a placeholder.

Comment: Why do you have this? I am only trying to having the user input only 4 characters. Your code makes the user enter 5 times with any amount of characters.

Comment: My error, both in code and in understanding your question, sorry.

Comment: It works. Now what if in the case I need letters on the first two characters and numbers on the last two.

Comment: Maybe you can start a new question for this?

Comment: I didn't want to ask too much or it looks like I am spamming the forum.